# Timer_Tick freezes the program

Tags: c#, timer

The following code where timer_tick event check for a condition match to trigger a text to speech and audio file playback. But when conditions met, the results are obtained as expected but the program freezes.

Also how to add a popup message box when these condition matches. It's ok for audio file or speech to repeat but I don't want to repeatedly open message boxes as the timer ticks.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)    
{
    label_time1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt");
    label6.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
    if (((DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm tt") == (textBox_ordertostart.Text) && (DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() == dateTimePicker2.Value.ToShortDateString()) && (checkBox_delivery.CheckState == 0) && (checkBox_pickup.CheckState != 0))))
    {
        comboBox_suburb.Enabled = false;
        checkBox_delivery.Enabled = false;
        mplayer = new SoundPlayer(WindowsFormsApplication17.Properties.Resources.good_morning);
        mplayer.Play();


        pbuilder.ClearContent();

        pbuilder.AppendText("Pickup order time start now");


        txt2speech.Speak(pbuilder);
        pbuilder.AppendBreak(PromptBreak.Medium);
    }
```

Comment: Are you using the [SpeechSynthesizer class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.aspx)?  If so, try `SpeakAsync` instead of `Speak`.

Comment: Great. Thats works great thanks. Any idea about messagebox?

Answer (score 0):

SpeechSynthesizer will hold the program when using the Speak function. Try using `SpeakAsync()` instead of `Speak()`, or you could start a new thread that runs the tick if you do not want the functions within your tick to block the UI of the program.